# Android accessing activity elements from service error

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a service which runs every 1 minute through an alarm manager. This service uses variables of the activity. So every 1 minute the service is fired, and reads data from the variables in the activity. The problem arises when android automatically kills the activity. So now ther service runs but it is unable to access the variables as the activity no longer exists.

What is the solution to this problem? What can I do ? Can I forbid android from shutting down the activity or can I do something else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't advise you to prevent android from shutting down your activity unless it has a higher priority for the user than, for example, an encoming call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store Data in SharedPreferences or Sqlite Database and Access it from SharedPreferences or Sqlite Database.

This data are not lost after Activity or application close.

Thanks.

Comment: So i store the data in SQL or sharedpreferences and i can access this data each time the service starts?